# Include other branch as subdirectory?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree, git-subrepo

I'm trying to set up a branch such that `branchA` has subfolders `A` and `B`, but `B` contains the contents of `branchB`.

I've been looking at `submodules`, `subtrees`, and `subrepos`, but I can't figure out what would do what I am looking for.

In order to prevent this from becoming an XY problem, my overarching situation is this: I'm developing an HTML5/JS game and I want to be able to test it on Github Pages.
So I want branch/subdirectory `gh-pages/play` to contain the branch `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Branches don't have folders / directories.  Branches *are*, quite simply, pointers to commit hash IDs (they start out as little files containing the raw hash ID, although they can be compressed into a sort of database of name-to-ID mapping, which Git does to save time and space for names that are not constantly changing).  So it's not possible directly.

It *is* possible to do what you want with submodules, though.  It's just tricky.  You will have to be very careful.  It's also not at all clear to me whether it will work at all with whatever this GitHub Pages thing may be, since *they* have to do a clone-and-checkout-with-submodule operation.

A Git *submodule* is really just another Git repository: you tell Git that some directory ("folder") such as `B` should be made by cloning a *different* Git repository, from some specific URL.  Once the clone is done, Git should then `cd` into the directory that the `git clone` makes, and `git checkout` one specific commit, by hash ID.

Well, what if for the "different" Git repository you want `git://host.name/path/to/url.git` to check out into sub-directory `B`, you specify the URL `git://host.name/path/to/url.git`?

The obvious danger here is the potential for endless recursion: Git checks out `url.git`, sees that it has a submodule, clones `url.git` to subdirectory `B`, checks out the commit inside `B`, sees that it has a submodule, clones it, `cd`s to what is now `B/B`, sees that it has a submodule, clones it, goes into `B/B/B`, sees that it has a submodule...

You avoid this endless recursion by:

- cloning without recursive submodule extraction (this is the default for `git clone`), and/or
- making very sure never to have the specific commit for the submodule include a commit that has the submodule as a submodule.

There's still one more problem: submodules check out one specific commit by *hash ID*, not by branch name.  You wanted `B` to be a self-clone that checks out branch `master` (which presumably never has a self-submodule `B`).  But all you can *get* is a `B` that checks out a specific Git hash ID, which is the hash ID you have stored in the commit in the superproject (which of course is this same repository).

There are some ways to dislodge the submodule off its one-specific-commit, including ways to make it check out a branch by branch-name.  These require running specific `git submodule` commands, which is part of what may prevent you from doing this on GitHub Pages (whatever that is, again).  But, assuming they let you do the submodule thing at all, you don't necessarily have to have it go by *name*: you can just make a new commit that stores the new `master` hash into the superproject.

Say, for instance, you're on branch `develop` in this superproject-with-self-as-submodule.  In `develop`, there's a `.gitmodules` file that says "I have a submodule / subproject you should clone into `B`, using this here URL" (which is the superproject's URL).  At the *tip commit* of develop you have a commit containing a "gitlink" tree entry that says "make a clone into `B`, looking up the subproject's URL in `.gitmodules`, and using hash `deadb0a`"—which is the hash of the *tip commit* of branch `master`.

Once you advance the tip of `master` to a *new* commit `ac0ffee`, you check out `develop` and make a *new* commit that has a "gitlink" tree entry that says "make a clone into `B` using hash `ac0ffee`".  Nothing else changes—just the hash ID—but now, when someone checks out `develop` *with* submodules enabled, they get the same commit in `B` that they would by checking out *branch* `master` in `B`, because branch `master` says "check out hash `ac0ffee`".

(Obviously this whole thing is a bit error-prone, as are submodules in general.  I suspect this is not a very wise path to go down.  But in theory, at least, it can work.)

Comment: Fun fact: submodules can now track branches.

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson: Hence *There are some ways to dislodge the submodule off its one-specific-commit, including ways to make it check out a branch by branch-name. These require running specific git submodule commands ...* You have to set the name of the branch (which I think you can save in the committed `.gitmodules` file) and then run `git submodule update --remote` or `git submodule checkout --remote`.